# How can I include "th:src" thymeleaf tag into an append() jquery method?

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

how can I include `"th:src="@{'....'}"` into an `append()` jquery method?

I have this code but the `<img`> tag doesn't work. I don't know how to use th:src into javascript.

Code:

```
    <script th:inline="javascript">
    
        /*<![CDATA[*/
            
            var imagenes = /*[[${imagenes}]]*/ null;
            console.log(imagenes);
            
            $.each(imagenes, function(index, value){
                
                if(index != 0) {
                    
                    $("#carousel-inner").append(
                            "<div class='carousel-item'>" +
                            "<img /*[[th:src=@{'/imagenes_productos/}" + value + "']]*/ class='d-block w-100' />" +
                            "</div>"
                    );
                }
                
            });
            
        /*]]>*/
        
    </script>
```

Code image:
[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S6KR.png)

Comment: You do not need to include screenshots of text in your questions - it is always better to provide the (formatted) text itself - which you do already provide, in this case.

Comment: Ok Andrew, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thymeleaf renders the Thymeleaf templates on the server and sends this to the browser as HTML. Once you are in the browser, you can further manipulate the page using JavaScript (and jQuery), but Thymeleaf is not active anymore at that point. So, you can't use `th:...` attributes as there is no Thymeleaf engine running in the browser to interpret those.

You should use the normal `src` attribute, not `th:src`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have thought other way to do what I wanted and I don't need use th:src inside any javascript.